# sort date fields to obtain earliest date

Tags: java, android

in my database , dates are stored in DD-mm-yyyy format , how can i sort this to obtain the earliest date ?

```
Cursor c = myDb.query(TABLE, new String[]{"dob"}, null, null, null, null, "dob");
```

I have selected it to order by dob field but its not ordered ...
This is the output for the above query

```
01-03 17:14:51.595: VERBOSE/ORDER DOB(1431): 01-11-1977
01-03 17:14:51.595: VERBOSE/ORDER DOB(1431): 01-12-1988
01-03 17:14:51.614: VERBOSE/ORDER DOB(1431): 15-01-1977
01-03 17:14:51.656: VERBOSE/ORDER DOB(1431): 31-01-1988
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you could say what database you are using and what the variable type of the dates is in your database. But you could probably just use SQL to order your dates.

Comment: sorry my bad , have edited my question , trying to query from SQlite in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case with sqlite and (afaik) it's lack of a date type, I would store the dates in [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) value in UTC time (this is a good practise anyway since you'll be timezone-independent) and then you can just sort by lowest value using `ORDER BY`.

You can just convert back to a readable date in your Java application (use SimpleDateFormat for example)

```
Date date = new Date(yourEpochValue);
SimpleDateFormat smf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
smf.setTimeZone(yourTimeZone);  
String dateString = smf.format(date);
```

You'd go about storing the value the other way around (if this is something you need to do)

Comment: Found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557972/how-can-i-get-sqlite-to-sort-by-date-properly-using-yyyy-mm-dd-format , so i changed it to YYYY-MM-DD format , now order by works ,but this is just a temp solution :(

Comment: Yeah that works, sort of. But look into NullUserException's answer, he's recommending the same thing as I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL database and store dates as type DATE or DATETIME it does not matter how the dates are shown. You can just use the sql `order by` statement. If my assumptions are wrong please provide more details.

Comment: have edited my question , am working in android with sqlite , tried ordering using order by but that s not proper so i got confused , does sqlite support date field ? i am using it as a text field

Comment: I am sorry, I am not a guru in sqlite on Android, so please refer the documentation. But as a work around you can always sort your collection in java using `Collections.sort()` that accepts comparator. Create your custom object that holds collection of data and comparator that knows to compare 2 such objects.